# How can I execute a callback after a massive multiple insert with Mongoose?

Tags: mongodb, node.js, mongoose

I have an object `results` that's very large (maybe over 1,000 items). I'm iterating over it to save to the DB but this seems very inefficient:

```
        for result in results
          item = new Item result
          item.save()
```

Is there a more optimal way to do this and THEN get a callback as opposed to a callback for EVERY save?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The async module will help a lot with this. You're probably looking for a queue.

https://github.com/caolan/async#queue

You may be getting near the edge of a the normal Node.js use case.

Comment: You might also look at the 'Step' and 'after' modules.  There are a bunch of control flow solutions listed on the Node modules page.

Comment: FWIW, 1,000 items won't be an issue for async, Step, or after to deal with.  No worries.